# EntityFieldQuery: Filter by field language

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, entities

How would I use EntityFieldQuery->fieldCondition() or similar to filter by field language? E.g. give me all nodes where field_description has items in English, or in LANGUAGE_NONE?

There is a `$language_group` parameter, but I think this won't do the job..

Background: I would like to improve entity_translation module for D7, see https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation/issues/2852983#comment-13039403

Comment: It seems `->entityCondition('language', 'en', '=')` filters by the first field table in the query, which depending on the order might be exactly the one we want. But this only applies in sql storage, no guarantee that other storage engines behave the same. It seems more coincidental than intentional.